# How do I count grep results for a string, but specify exclusions?

Tags: shell, sorting, count, awk, uniq

I have maillog file with below parameters

```
relay=mx3.xyz.com

relay=mx3.xyz.com

relay=mx1.xyz.com

relay=mx1.xyz.com

relay=mx2.xyz.com

relay=home.xyz.abc.com

relay=127.0.0.1
```

I want to count all relay except 127.0.0.1

Output should like this

```
total relay= 6

mx3.xyz.com = 2

mx1.xyz.com = 2

mx2.xyz.com = 1

home.xyz.abc.com = 1
```

Comment: What language are you working in? What have you tried?

Comment: dear faiz, thanks for your help but your  script gave me mail ID and relay count.

Comment: Do you really have all those blank lines in the source file?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using awk:

```
awk -F= '$2 != "127.0.0.1"  &&  /relay/ {count[$2]++; total++} 
  END { print "total relay = "total; 
        for (k in count) { print k" = " count[k]}
      }' maillog
```

And you could also make do with just `uniq` and `grep`, though you won't get your total this way:

```
 grep relay maillog  | cut -d= -f2 | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | uniq -c
```

And if you don't hate perl:

```
perl -ne '/relay=(.*)/ and $1 ne "127.0.0.1" and ++$t and $h{$1}++;
  END {print "total = $t\n"; 
       print "$_ = $h{$_}\n" foreach keys %h;
  }' maillog
```

Comment: input has empty lines, your solution will print those empty line counts too.

Comment: I want to grep relay=anything (given above in question) from my maillog but should not 127.0.0.1 and count them, is it possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand... most of the answers seem to do what you say you want - what's the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 2):

here you go:

```
 awk -F= '$2!="127.0.0.1"&&$2{t++;a[$2]++} END{print "total relay="t; for(x in a)print x"="a[x]}' yourfile
```

the output would be:

```
total relay=6
mx2.xyz.com=1
mx1.xyz.com=2
mx3.xyz.com=2
home.xyz.abc.com=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use awk for this (@Faiz's answer). However I worked out this excruciating pipeline

```
cut -d= -f2 filename | grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' -e 127.0.0.1 | sort | uniq -c | tee >(echo "$(bc <<< $(sed -e 's#[[:alpha:]].\+$#+#' -e '$a0')) total") | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\2 = \1/' | tac
```

outputs

```
total = 6
mx3.xyz.com = 2
mx2.xyz.com = 1
mx1.xyz.com = 2
home.xyz.abc.com = 1
```

Please do not upvote this answer ;)

Comment: I think this is a brilliant hack!